# Does aforge.net support OCR?

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr, aforge, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am developing a number plate recognition application. I have completed a number plate extraction part and now comes the recognition. I have used Aforge.Net so far and does it support OCR as well?

If not is there a particular OCR engine that could be used with C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AForge.net doesn't directly support OCR, but you can make code to make it do ocr with forward trained neural networks, or you can do this with Template matching which is sported in AForge.net